# Awk coping when column is occassionly empty

Tags: linux, awk

I have output from a foreach loop in the form:

```
ABC123603LP    44Bq    AAAA       
ABC123603P     3BU     AAAA       
ABC123603ZZP           AAAA       
ABC123604DP    3BU     BBBB     
ABC123604LP    44Bq    BBBB      
ABC123605AP    4q      CCCC    
ABC123605DP    33BGU   CCCC    
ABC123606AP    35Bjq   DDDD     
ABC123606DP    4B      DDDD
```

From this I wish to print columns 1 and 2 to the terminal with

```
echo ... | awk '{print $1, $2}'
```

However the third row and others prints ABC123603ZZP AAAA as the second column is blank in this case. How do I get around this?

Comment: Do you want to omit the lines where the second column is empty?

Comment: Is the data fixed-width or tab-separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the number of field before you print:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}{ if (NF==2)  print $1; else print $1, $2}' file
ABC123603LP     44Bq
ABC123603P      3BU
ABC123603ZZP
ABC123604DP     3BU
ABC123604LP     44Bq
ABC123605AP     4q
ABC123605DP     33BGU
ABC123606AP     35Bjq
ABC123606DP     4B
```

Comment: I suspect he has tab-delimited input so we should just set FS accordingly: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{print $1,$2}'`. Otherwise I'd use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{print $1,(NF==2 ? "" : $2)}'` so he gets consistently 2-field output which would make it easier if he needs to do further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed instead:

```
echo ... | sed 's/\(A[^ ]*[\t ]*\)\([^ \t]*[0-9][^ \t]*\)*.*/\1 \2/'
```

Comment: This gives me the same output as the echo. With column 3 included (AAAA etc)

Comment: @moadeep do you need column 3 as `ABC123603ZZP    `, or omited?

Comment: @billybob I need column 3 omitted. I have a working solution now

Answer (score 0):

One technique to remove the last column is to make awk think there are 1 fewer fields:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{NF--; print}'
```